# Unable to use R Markdown in RStudio due to required packages

Tags: package, r-markdown, rstudio

I am unable to use R Markdown in RStudio and am trying to figure out what is going wrong.

I simply open RStudio, go to File > New File > R Markdown...

And then the following pop-up message appears:
[image]

And so I click "Yes".

And then I find the following in my "Jobs" display:

```
** Installing R Package Dependencies for R Markdown: 'glue', 'knitr', 'rmarkdown', 'xfun'



[1/5] Installing glue...

Installing package into 'C:/Users/lino/Documents/R/win-library/3.5'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
     binary source needs_compilation
glue  1.4.0  1.4.2              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/glue_1.4.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 157284 bytes (153 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 153 KB

package 'glue' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\lino\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpm8AlsN\downloaded_packages


[2/5] Installing xfun...

Installing package into 'C:/Users/lino/Documents/R/win-library/3.5'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
     binary source needs_compilation
xfun   0.13   0.25              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/xfun_0.13.zip'
package 'xfun' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Content type 'application/zip' length 184719 bytes (180 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 180 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\lino\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpm8AlsN\downloaded_packages


[3/5] Installing knitr...

Installing package into 'C:/Users/lino/Documents/R/win-library/3.5'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
also installing the dependency 'xfun'


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
      binary source needs_compilation
xfun    0.13   0.25              TRUE
knitr   1.28   1.33             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/xfun_0.13.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 184719 bytes (180 KB)
=======package 'xfun' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
===========================================
downloaded 180 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\lino\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpm8AlsN\downloaded_packages
installing the source package 'knitr'

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/knitr_1.33.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 892378 bytes (871 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 871 KB

* installing *source* package 'knitr' ...
** package 'knitr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'xfun' 0.13 is being loaded, but >= 0.21 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'knitr'
* removing 'C:/Users/lino/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/knitr'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/lino/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/knitr'


[4/5] Installing tinytex...

In R CMD INSTALL

The downloaded source packages are in
    'C:\Users\lino\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpm8AlsN\downloaded_packages'
Installing package into 'C:/Users/lino/Documents/R/win-library/3.5'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
also installing the dependency 'xfun'


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
        binary source needs_compilation
xfun      0.13   0.25              TRUE
tinytex   0.22   0.33             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/xfun_0.13.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 184719 bytes (180 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 180 KB

package 'xfun' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\lino\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpm8AlsN\downloaded_packages
installing the source package 'tinytex'

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tinytex_0.33.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 30085 bytes (29 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 29 KB

* installing *source* package 'tinytex' ...
** package 'tinytex' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'xfun' 0.13 is being loaded, but >= 0.23 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'tinytex'
* removing 'C:/Users/lino/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/tinytex'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/lino/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/tinytex'


[5/5] Installing rmarkdown...

In R CMD INSTALL

The downloaded source packages are in
    'C:\Users\lino\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpm8AlsN\downloaded_packages'
Installing package into 'C:/Users/lino/Documents/R/win-library/3.5'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies 'knitr', 'tinytex', 'xfun'

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/knitr_1.33.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 892378 bytes (871 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 871 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tinytex_0.33.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 30085 bytes (29 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 29 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/xfun_0.25.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 112755 bytes (110 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 110 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rmarkdown_2.10.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3248794 bytes (3.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.1 MB

* installing *source* package 'xfun' ...
** package 'xfun' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'xfun'
* removing 'C:/Users/lino/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/xfun'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/lino/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/xfun'
In R CMD INSTALL
* installing *source* package 'knitr' ...
** package 'knitr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'xfun' 0.13 is being loaded, but >= 0.21 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'knitr'
* removing 'C:/Users/lino/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/knitr'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/lino/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/knitr'
In R CMD INSTALL
* installing *source* package 'tinytex' ...
** package 'tinytex' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'xfun' 0.13 is being loaded, but >= 0.23 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'tinytex'
* removing 'C:/Users/lino/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/tinytex'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/lino/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/tinytex'
In R CMD INSTALL
* installing *source* package 'rmarkdown' ...
** package 'rmarkdown' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'rlang'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'rmarkdown'
* removing 'C:/Users/lino/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rmarkdown'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/lino/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rmarkdown'
In R CMD INSTALL

The downloaded source packages are in
    'C:\Users\lino\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpm8AlsN\downloaded_packages'


<U+2714> Packages successfully installed.
Warning messages:
1: In utils::install.packages("knitr", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
  installation of package 'knitr' had non-zero exit status
2: In utils::install.packages("tinytex", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
  installation of package 'tinytex' had non-zero exit status
3: In utils::install.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/",  :
  installation of package 'xfun' had non-zero exit status
4: In utils::install.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/",  :
  installation of package 'knitr' had non-zero exit status
5: In utils::install.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/",  :
  installation of package 'tinytex' had non-zero exit status
6: In utils::install.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/",  :
  installation of package 'rmarkdown' had non-zero exit status
```

I then try again, and proceed with File > New File > R Markdown...

I once again see this pop-up message:
[image]

This is basically the same as before, except I am no longer told I need to install `glue`.

And so I click "Yes". I then go to open a new R Markdown, and the same pop-up message appears (the second pop-up message I received). This appears to be a cycle that is just not going anyone.

How can I fix this so that I can start using R Markdown again? I am not sure what went wrong, since I used to be able to use R Markdown fine on this same computer. Apologies if I posted to much of the error messages, I was not sure how much was necessary to properly display the actual issue I should be focusing on. Is there a simple fix to this? I have already tried reinstalling RStudio and it has not helped.

Comment: It seems that the installation of `knitr`, `rmarkdown`, and `xfun` failed. Do you have these packages on your R now? Did you try to update these packages before you encountered the error message?